# How to implement HashSet.GetOrAdd(T) extension method in .NET 6 or .NET 7 using CollectionsMarshal

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, hashset

On dotnet runtime Github repo there was [a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21603) for adding `HashSet.GetOrAdd(T)` - similar to

```
public static T GetOrAdd<T>(this HashSet<T> hashSet, T equalValue)
{
    if (hashSet.TryGetValue(equalValue, out var actualValue))
        return actualValue;

    hashSet.Add(equalValue);
    return equalValue;
}
```

but without a duplicate hash lookup (performance impact).

That issue was closed with the following resolution:

> We're going down CollectionsMarshal route for [#15059](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15059), we
> should probably consider a similar approach for HashSet

In issue [#15059](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15059#issuecomment-954708195) the last comment has an example of **CollectionsMarshal** usage for a **Dictionary**:

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
where TKey : notnull
{
    if (dictionary == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));

    if (valueFactory == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valueFactory));            

    ref TValue? value = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out bool exists);
    if (!exists)
        value = valueFactory(key);

    return value!;
}
```

I've tried to use the same approach to implement `HashSet.GetOrAdd(T)` extension but failed - I don't have any idea how to get **key** value for `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault()` method.

Both issues are locked as resolved and limited to collaborators - so I cannot ask directly there.

Comment: You can't implement this without grody reflection; only the runtime authors can. .NET being open source now, you can of course always try to write up a pull request. On the other hand, from the tickets I only read good intentions without an actual API proposal writeup, so you may well consider opening a new issue. Do note that retrieving a value from a `HashSet` this way is a *much* less common scenario than a `Dictionary`, as dictionaries are ubiquitous throughout the runtime itself as well, so it may be deemed to have not as much added value. Even the dictionary case is considered "niche".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21603#issuecomment-1452432653) from MS (only creating an extension method that performs double lookup is possible):

> For the record, using CollectionsMarshal for HashSet was proven to be
> not viable because you can't do ref returns on keys - [#82840 (comment)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82840#issuecomment-1450463397)
>
> That being said, consensus is that a GetOrAdd method for HashSet is
> not particularly valuable compared to just using HashSet.Add except
> for the rare scenario where you need to access the actual instance
> stored in the HashSet - [#82875 (comment)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82875#issuecomment-1452036878)